# How to convert convert .CAF file into .MP3 in iOS?

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder

I am recording audio file. It is recorded with .caf extension.

How can I convert this format into .mp3 format?

Answer (score 0):

There is a open source project [lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) . The challenge would be making it work for iphone.   [This](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-cross-compiling-libraries-for-ios-armv6armv7i386/) would give a direction towards cross compiling for ios.

There is also an [iOSMp3Recorder](https://github.com/rpplusplus/iOSMp3Recorder) available on GIT and one another example 
[Record and audio conversion](http://code4app.net/ios/Record-and-audio-conversion/516e58b26803fad815000007) in internet.

I hope above examples may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lame, you can do this. Ther is no default function for this. It will also reduce the file size also. For 60 second audio file .caf will take approx 5mb - 10mb but after converting to .mp3 it will take 0.6mb to 0.7mb. Set 'Enable Bitcode' to 'NO' in build setting for new xocde, otherwise you will get error. 
For sample code use this [LINK](https://github.com/rpplusplus/iOSMp3Recorder).